# Is it possible to restrict connection to database in Docker container at particular interface on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: networking, docker, ubuntu-16.04, ifconfig, ufw

I have MySQL database on a server (I use [Percona](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/) in **Docker** container) with several network interfaces.

My system is **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**.

```
ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:...
          inet addr:95.*.*.*

eth1      Link encap:...
          inet addr:10.*.*.*
```

Is it possible to restrict access with `ufw` to a database on `eth0` interface but allow on `eth1`?

So It will be able to access to DB with `10.*.*.*:6603` and not will be able to access with `95.*.*.*:6603`.

**Update (04.03.2017):**

I have used that command to add a rule:

```
sudo ufw deny in on eth0 to any port 6603 from any proto tcp
```

Status:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
6603/tcp on eth0           DENY        Anywhere
6603/tcp (v6) on eth0      DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

But I despite deny rule I can enter to my DB with `MySQL` client.

**But `6603` port is still open:**

```
nmap -p 6603 95.85.54.75

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-03-04 16:14 UTC
Nmap scan report for 95.85.54.75
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
6603/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.65 seconds
```

Comment: Does [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/270715/ubuntu-ufw-set-a-rule-on-a-per-interface-basis) work for you?

Comment: @Kevin, I would post this as an answer and quote the relevant information, and also edit the info to fit his scenario

Comment: @Kevin I tried your advice but port is still opened. Can you help me to find error in my rule or give me advice to solve my problem (see question updates for details)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Docker tampers with the firewall rules.

According these posts (*[The dangers of UFW + Docker](http://blog.viktorpetersson.com/post/101707677489/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker)*, *[How to set Docker 1.12+ to NOT interfere with IPTABLES/FirewallD](http://blog.samcater.com/how-to-set-docker-1-12-to-not-interfere-with-iptables-firewalld/)*):

- I have created file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with content:

  ```
  {
      "iptables": false
  }
  ```
- I have added rule to ufw:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow in on eth1 to any port 6603
  ```

  to allow connections from ufw only.
- reboot the docker daemon

  ```
  sudo service docker stop
  sudo service docker start
  ```

**Note:** this fix works only for containers created with `docker run...`. For containers created with Docker Swarm this fix doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ufw`, you can bind MySQL to one single interface.

The mysqld configuration file (usually at  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) has an option called `bind-address` that let you set a single IP address, (like 10.0.4.25, for example) to force MySQL to listen only on that interface.

However it is not a bullet proof solution, because in hosts that use the *[weak host model](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Host_model)* (like some linux distros) is possible to connect to services bound on one interface from another one.

Comment: That's not necessarily better. Linux considers IPv4 addresses to be host-owned, not interface-owned, so binding to an address _does not_ automatically bind to its interface. (The latter is possible but needs a separate sockopt.) Therefore, if someone is on the same link, e.g. another 146.x.x.x server, then they can still easily connect even to services bound to another interface's address. A firewall rule meanwhile will _always_ work.

Comment: @grawity It's very hard to believe you.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first person to say that, and yet I've successfully *cough* used that misfeature in the past... Take a look at "strong host model" (preferred for IPv6) vs "weak host model" (common for IPv4) for more information. (By default Linux will even answer ARP queries on the 'wrong' interface; you can tune this with arp_filter/arp_ignore, but even then a manually added route or ARP entry still allows connections.)

Comment: @grawity You are right. I didn't know about it. it's really true that *You learn something new every day*. I modified my answer to include that.